# Unable to merge in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, push

I am a newcomer to mercurial. I have recently set up a repository with 2 colleagues and am having difficulty with pushing my code. [I am using command-line hg in Windows]. In particular when I push I get a dialogue like the following:

```
>hg commit -u petermr

>hg push
pushing to http://bitbucket.org/petermr/polyinfo/
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote heads!
(did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)
>hg merge
abort: there is nothing to merge

>hg status
```

I am afraid to commit using push -f as I think that will create multiple heads and cause problems for our group.

When I try to merge I get a dialogue something like:

```
>hg merge -f
merging src/test/resources/PMR/algorithm/cmlAll.xml
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/algorithm/cmlAll.xml appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
merging src/test/resources/PMR/irregular/cmlAll.xml
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/irregular/cmlAll.xml appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
merging src/test/resources/PMR/massChange/cmlAll.xml
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/massChange/cmlAll.xml appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
```

Since there are several hundred files I cannot type "y" for each and I can't find a way of merging them all together.

**UPDATE** I have tried the first (2) answers and still have a problem:

```
>hg pull
pulling from http://bitbucket.org/petermr/polyinfo/
searching for changes
no changes found

>hg merge
abort: outstanding uncommitted merges
```

**UPDATE** in response to @tonfa I cannot commit:

```
>hg commit
abort: unresolved merge conflicts (see hg resolve)
```

**UPDATE** @balpha (I have changed the name of the owner to Foo)

```
>hg parent
changeset:   24:9ec904d2d5a2
tag:         tip
user:        petermr
date:        Sat Jan 09 16:40:38 2010 +0000
summary:     trying to sync

changeset:   22:360aedb72f0e
parent:      21:89c4bd671bd3
parent:      18:3cffa8ca3a2a
user:        Foo (not me)
date:        Fri Jan 08 16:15:50 2010 +0000
summary:     merged


>hg tip
changeset:   24:9ec904d2d5a2
tag:         tip
user:        petermr
date:        Sat Jan 09 16:40:38 2010 +0000
summary:     trying to sync
```

**UPDATE**

> hg heads

```
changeset:   24:9ec904d2d5a2
tag:         tip
user:        petermr
date:        Sat Jan 09 16:40:38 2010 +0000
summary:     trying to sync

changeset:   22:360aedb72f0e
parent:      21:89c4bd671bd3
parent:      18:3cffa8ca3a2a
user:        Foo (not me)
date:        Fri Jan 08 16:15:50 2010 +0000
summary:     merged
```

**UPDATE** following @balpha comments below who suggests revert which asks for a revison (is this a number? If so how do I find it?)

```
>hg revert --all
abort: uncommitted merge - please provide a specific revision
```

**UPDATE** still cannot merge...

```
>hg revert --all -r tip
reverting .hgignore
reverting .hgignore~
reverting src\test\java\org\xmlcml\cml\converters\polyinfo\RegressionTest.java
reverting src\test\resources\PMR\algorithm\cmlAll.xml
reverting src\test\resources\PMR\irregular\cmlAll.xml
reverting src\test\resources\PMR\massChange\cmlAll.xml
reverting src\test\resources\PMR\massChangeOk\cmlAll.xml
reverting src\test\resources\PMR\ok\P340076.both.svg
reverting src\test\resources\PMR\ok\P340076.p.svg
reverting src\test\resources\PMR\ok\P340076.r.svg
reverting src\test\resources\PMR\ratio\cmlAll.xml

>hg status
M .hgignore
M .hgignore~
M src\test\resources\PMR\algorithm\cmlAll.xml
M src\test\resources\PMR\irregular\cmlAll.xml
M src\test\resources\PMR\massChange\cmlAll.xml
M src\test\resources\PMR\massChangeOk\cmlAll.xml
M src\test\resources\PMR\ok\P340076.both.svg
M src\test\resources\PMR\ok\P340076.p.svg
M src\test\resources\PMR\ok\P340076.r.svg
M src\test\resources\PMR\ratio\cmlAll.xml
? src\test\resources\PMR\bug\P020006work.both.svg
? src\test\resources\PMR\irregular\cmlAll.xml.resolve

>hg merge
abort: outstanding uncommitted merges

>hg commit
abort: unresolved merge conflicts (see hg resolve)
```

Note that

```
hg resolve -all
```

brings up the original problem of having to answer "y" to hundreds of individual questions and I don't know then whether it will resolve the problem. Your help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE** @balpha suggested cleaning - this seems to have made progress

```
>hg update --clean -r tip
10 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

>hg merge
merging src/test/resources/PMR/algorithm/cmlAll.xml
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/algorithm/cmlAll.xml appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
merging src/test/resources/PMR/irregular/cmlAll.xml
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/irregular/cmlAll.xml appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
merging src/test/resources/PMR/massChange/cmlAll.xml
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/massChange/cmlAll.xml appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
merging src/test/resources/PMR/massChangeOk/cmlAll.xml
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/massChangeOk/cmlAll.xml appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
merging src/test/resources/PMR/ok/P340076.both.svg
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/ok/P340076.both.svg appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
merging src/test/resources/PMR/ok/P340076.p.svg
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/ok/P340076.p.svg appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
merging src/test/resources/PMR/ok/P340076.r.svg
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/ok/P340076.r.svg appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
merging src/test/resources/PMR/ratio/cmlAll.xml
 output file src/test/resources/PMR/ratio/cmlAll.xml appears unchanged
was merge successful (yn)? y
2 files updated, 8 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)

>hg merge
abort: outstanding uncommitted merges

>hg merge -f
abort: outstanding uncommitted merges

>hg commit -u petermr -m "still trying to sy
nc"

>hg merge
abort: there is nothing to merge

>hg push
pushing to http://bitbucket.org/petermr/polyinfo/
searching for changes
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: petermr
password:
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 4 changesets with 298 changes to 290 files
bb/acl: petermr is allowed. accepted payload.
quota: 13.3 MB in use, 150.0 MB available (8.87% used)
```

Comment: just commit the result of the merge.

Comment: please post the output of `hg parent` and `hg tip`

Comment: `hg revert --all` (I assume you have commited all your "real" changes?), `hg merge`, `hg commit`

Comment: sorry, forgot: `hg revert --all -r tip` (revision can either be a number (24 in this case), a hash (9ec9) or, which is easiest in this case, a tag. "tip" is a special-case tag that's always given to the most recent commit.)

Comment: I just checked the docs; `revert` won't change the working directory's parents, so you also have to `hg up --clean -r tip`. After that, your working directory is exactly as it was when you commited. You should then be able to merge. BTW, we have to clean up here a little bit when we're done :-)

Comment: Concerning those yes/no questions: They only come up because you `--force`d the merge on a non-clean working directory. When you have a clean one and just `hg merge` the other head into it, the only thing that might happen are merge conflicts.

Comment: Seems to have worked. I'm a little confused over those y/n questions though. I've cloned your repo to take a look at it.

Comment: When I try to do this merge I get merge conflicts in exactly those files that are reported to "appear unchanged" in your output. These questions suggest that you have configured a different merge tool than the standard one. You might want to check with Foo [whose name is public, btw---it's a public repo] whether those files look the way you both expect.

Comment: maybe it's better to use mercurial mailing lists?

Comment: @bialix when I asked this question I thought it would be a fairly simple problem and SO was a reasonable place to ask. In fact it seems to have raised some unanswered technical problems. It's possible that some of the problems are due to the toolset. [No idea why this Q has been downvoted - I assumed that this was just the sort of thing that SO catered for

Comment: +1 for updating this question so well.  Thanks.  (I'm still stuck, but still)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your local clone of the repo is probably not up-to-date. Do a

```
hg pull
```

to change that. Now you have two heads locally (your own previous tip and the tip of the bitbucket repo). Now

```
hg merge
```

to merge the two heads and

```
hg commit -m "Merged before pushing"
```

Now your local repo has only one head, and this head is a child of the bitbucket head, so pushing will *not* create a remote head anymore:

```
hg push
```

and you're done.

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow me a merge - see UPDATE

Comment: Accepted answer, but see discussion on the question for details

Answer (score 5):

Before you push code to a remote repository, first ensure your local repo is clean and has no outstanding merges.

Then, do a hg pull from the remote repository. This will create 2 heads on your local repository.

Do a local merge, and commit (resolving any conflicts).

Finally, push to the remote repository.

Do not, in general, push to a remote repository if multiple heads will be created there.

Comment: +1 because the "repo must be clean" part was the crucial thing in this case

Comment: @Tarydon: "First ensure your local repo is clean and has no outstanding merges."  Can you explain how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You might not want to commit the merge even locally.  The way to clean out and start over again (from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue1533) seems to be "hg update -C ".

As alluded to above, it seems as if "hg revert -a" ought to work, but doesn't seem to.

Comment: I had exactly the problem described atop the original question, and found that copying all my changed files out, `hg update -C`, and then copying back changes worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use TortoiseHg instead of the command line tool, it is simpler and graphically shows the state of the repository, so you won't be confused with all the commands.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. Turned out the root cause is the "exclude" extension of the Mercurial. By turning off the extension temporarily, the problem been fixed. 
Referring to the "exclude" extension page, owner admitted it's a known issue.